# Can Ubuntu 16.04 dual boot access the GPU on a Windows machine?

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, gpu

I know that the GPU can't be accessed through an Ubuntu Virtual Machine; but can it be accessed through a dual boot?

Comment: Assuming that you have a compatible graphics card, then using a dual boot Ubuntu becomes the operating system on your computer and has access to all hardware resources.  Including the GPU

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. When Ubuntu is installed to the hardware (as in a Dual boot situation) it has access to all the attached devices as any other OS would. So long as the devices are compatible (eg. functional drivers exist) Ubuntu should be able to access all resources (as indicated by Charles Green's comment).

When you install an OS in a Virtual Machine, it is provided virtual hardware by the virtualization software*. Depending on the virtualization software you are using, certain hardware may or may not be supported.

*Note: This is the general idea behind virtualization, however there are various optimizations (eg. PCI and VGA passthrough modules) that allow more direct access to the physical hardware. Thus this general statement is not accurate in all situations.